# Earle latch properties

Tags: digital-logic, latch

I just read a textbook describing the Earle latch, but no truth table was given for this device. Does anyone know this truth table?

Also, the book states that by varying the complementary clocking signals, the device can be made to have other useful features but again no details were given. Does anyone have knowledge of what features the author could be referring to?

Answer (score 4):

The [Earle latch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Earle_latch):

[image]

The truth table can be derived from the circuit diagram:

```
----------------------
Clock  Data  Out(n+1)
----------------------
  0     0     Out(n)
  0     1     Out(n)
  1     0       0
  1     1       1
----------------------
```

One useful feature of Earle's latch is that it has a constant delay of 2 gates for any input. And this makes Earle latch *hazard-free*.

Comment: @ nidhin: How can that be the truth table, the circuit has two clock inputs, your truth table only has one ???

Comment: @pamgifford they are complementary signals. \$\overline{Clock} = not\ Clock\$.

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP also wanted to know what happened if non-complementary clock inputs were provided:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6IagT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

```
----------------------
PClk  NClk  Data   Q'
----------------------
  0     0     0    0
  0     1     0    Q
  1     0     0    0
  1     1     0    Q
  0     0     1    Q
  0     1     1    Q
  1     0     1    1
  1     1     1    1
----------------------
```

In other words, the active-low clock signal (NClk) gates the reset action of the latch, while the active-high clock (PClk) gates the set action.